# reloadData doen't draw cells in tableview

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitableview

```
- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
[super viewDidAppear:animated];

NSString *show=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[res objectAtIndex:18]];
float f=[show floatValue];
show1=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.2f %%",f];
[show1  retain];
[self.tableView reloadData];
}


- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
UITableViewCell *cell = nil;
if (indexPath.row % 2 == 0) {
    // EVEN
    cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"EvenCell"];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleValue1 reuseIdentifier:@"EvenCell"] autorelease];
        UIView *bg = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:cell.frame];
        UIColor *colour = [[UIColor alloc] initWithRed: (208.0/255.f) green: (231.0/255.f) 
                                                  blue: (241.0/255.f) alpha: 1.0];
        bg.backgroundColor = colour; 
        cell.backgroundView = bg;
        cell.textLabel.backgroundColor = bg.backgroundColor;
        [bg release];
        cell.detailTextLabel.backgroundColor=[UIColor clearColor];
        cell.detailTextLabel.text=show1;
    }
    cell.textLabel.text = [array objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator;

} 
else {
    // ODD
    cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"OddCell"];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleValue1 reuseIdentifier:@"OddCell"] autorelease];
        UIView *bg = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:cell.frame];

        UIColor *colour = [[UIColor alloc] initWithRed: (143.0/255.f) green: (169.0/255.f) 
                                                  blue: (180.0/255.f) alpha: 1.0];
        bg.backgroundColor = colour;
        cell.backgroundView = bg;
        cell.textLabel.backgroundColor = bg.backgroundColor;
        [bg release];
    }
    cell.textLabel.text = [array objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator;


} 
return cell;
}
```

This is my code as you can see i reload data in viewDidAppear show1 is my data that needs to put in the tableView's cell in detailLabel.text. Now don't look at my odd cell part cos its not useable atm. I got only 1 cell and its even cell. Now my problem is when i delete the [self.tableView reloadData]; line it works good not updating but it shows the cell.When i put it i can't see a cell in tableView its all empty any idea why? where am i doing wrong?

edit1:

```
  cell.backgroundView = bg;
    cell.textLabel.backgroundColor = bg.backgroundColor;
    [bg release];
    cell.detailTextLabel.backgroundColor=[UIColor clearColor];
}
cell.detailTextLabel.text=show1;
cell.textLabel.text = [array objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator;
```

okey i change it and get it out of if but still i can't see any table cell its all empty just the navigation bar name and empty cell . Why its empty anyidea?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The code "cell.detailTextLabel.text=show1;" is inside the if condition of if( cell==nil)
When you are reloading the cell if the cell is already available you will not go in the code block and you changed value of show1 won't be displayed.

The code
`cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"EvenCell"];`

Checks if their is a cell that it can re-use. If it finds that then it would return the same

Comment: you are right mate i delete the if statment there but still don't put the cell i see empty page if you want i can put image

Comment: The solution is not to delete the if statement, but add the statement of `cell.detailTextLabel.text=show1` after the if condition just above the `cell.textLabel.text = [array objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];`. Also can you check what is the value of the show1 when you are trying to reload the data and is the detail text color different from the background color that you are setting

Answer (score 3):

The String value `Show1` is set only during initialing the cell.

```
cell.detailTextLabel.text=show1;
```

Put the above line below this line and check.

```
cell.textLabel.text = [array objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
```

Comment: you are right mate but i still can't see the cell its still blank empty there is no cell in it